# jQuery trigger not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I have a input type file, I set it display none and use the other button to trigger it.

I test on every browser, works fine but Safari.

```
$("#file_button").click(function () {
    $("#image").trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="file_button" value="Image">
<input type="file" id="image" style="display:none"/>
```

Comment: I think this may be a browser security feature. I know `file` inputs are heavily restricted as to what you can do with them programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a common problem, although the correct cross-browser way to achieve this is by making the `input type="file"` transparent and positioned absolutely above the desired click element.

Something like this:

```
<div class="file-wrap">
  <span>Click me</span>
  <input type="file" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.file-wrap{
  position: relative;
}
input[type="file"]{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

This way, the user thinks they're clicking on whatever you style your span to be, but you've been sneaky and placed your file input above it.

A quick note: Don't put it inside a `<button></button>` - IE doesn't like this and removes the `input type="file"` *completely* with no error messages when it parses the page.

Comment: but every browser input type file width height and position are all different

Comment: Yes. But generally if you add `top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;width:100%;height:100%;` it works out fine. This is the standard technique currently. See the source of http://mega.co.nz for an example. For their massive button, they use multiple file inputs.